# Intellij: IBM Websphere Missing classes

Tags: jar, import, intellij-idea, websphere

What are the jars/libraries I need to import to get these Interfaces?

```
import com.ibm.websphere.jtaextensions.ExtendedJTATransaction;
import com.ibm.websphere.uow.UOWSynchronizationRegistry;
import com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWManager;
```

Did a google search and didn't find any jars. I'm not sure, what to import. Any clue? I'm setting up the environment in Intellij and I have some compile errors due to missing jars/libs for the above mentioned import statements.

[image]

Can someone point out where I can find these required libraries.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JARs containing API/SPI classes for compilation are under `WAS_HOME/dev/`.  The classes you're referring to are in `WAS_HOME/dev/was_public.jar`.